# Apache NiFi ExecuteStreamCommand removing double quotes while passing arguments

Tags: apache-nifi

I am having NiFi flows for serving APIs with HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse. In one such flow, I have a RunMongoAggregation and the output from this aggregation are being passed on to EvaluateJSONPath to a final ExecuteStreamCommand processor.

The input of ExecuteStreamCommand looks like this:

```
"${http.param.floorid}";${fourteendaysback};${sevendaysback};${currentday};${AverageTimeTakenPerJob};${TotalTimesForkliftLoaded};${TotalTimesForkliftUnloaded};${TotalTimesForkliftOnHalt};${TotalJobsCompleted};
```

where http.param.floorid= Shop Floor 1

In the ExecuteStreamCommand, I am passing ; as a delimiter and the file for execution is a shell script

For debugging I printed the arguments that are being passed to the shell script which in turn runs a python script.

Output:

```
#From List Queue <the below output coming from the echo statement within the shell script>
Shop Floor 1 1547251200000 1547856000000 1548374400000 23.133333333333333 150 132
```

It is not taking the last 2 value for TotalTimesForkliftOnHalt and TotalJobsCompleted.

From Data Provenance:

```
execution.command.args
"Shop Floor 1";1547251200000 ;1547856000000 ;1548374400000;23.133333333333333;150;132;18;132;

execution.error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "asset_efficiency_trend.py", line 13, in <module> TotalTimesForkliftOnHalt=int(sys.argv[8]) IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I am running the shell script from the terminal with all the arguments (with the 1st argument in double quotes), it is running fine.

I checked for couple of other flows where I am using ExecuteStreamCommand and where the same "${http.param.floorid}" is being used along with other parameters. They are running fine without any issues.

I have tried using an UpdateAttribute processor to prepend and append double-quotes around floorid. But still no luck.

Is there any maximum number of arguments that I can pass in ExecuteStreamCommand?
How can I resolve this?

Comment: please simplify your question. could you create a simple command that just iterates parameters and prints them out. call this command through ExecuteStreamCommand  with some statically defined parameters and show in your question what you pass and what you get. I guess there is a trick with double-quotes usage.. try to remove them

Comment: Ah, I figured out the source of this error. My flow looks like this:
Input Port -> UpdateAttribute->RouteOnAttribute->RunMongoAggregation->RouteOnAttribute->EvaluateJSON->ExecuteStreamCommand.

When I ran ExecuteStreamCommand with hardcoded parameters, it worked fine. So for further debugging, I printed each input parameter to the shell script in newline. Found that 2 blank newlines are coming because of which 2 arguments are being dropped (total no of input argument was 9). 
In the UpdateAttribute, I am calculating 3 parameters. Among them, 2 are generating newline characters.